# How to Configure Log4Net to Enable Logging for a Particular Class

Tags: log4net

Given an assembly with 2 classes, Foo and Bar, via the configuration file, how to I enable logging at the Info Level for Foo, and the Warning level for Bar?

Comment: Did you give [the documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html) a look?

Comment: @AdiLester I did but when I searched for "Enable", I didn't find it anywhere.  After some more searching I did find this site: http://www.eyecatch.no/blog/2012/08/logging-with-log4net-in-c-sharp/  It looks like you just have to do `<logger name="MyNamespace.MyClass">` but I'm not at work to test anymore.  I'll have to research tomorrow and answer it myself unless someone confirms it first.

Comment: @AdiLester I also didn't find anything in the page that defines specifically how to enable it / disable it for a particular class.

Answer (score 1):

What configuration you use, depends on how the Logger is created.  The basic configuration looks like this:

```xml
<logger name="(INSERT LOGGER NAME HERE)">
  <level value="(WHATEVER LOG LEVEL TO APPLY FOR THIS PARTICULAR LOGGER)" />
</logger>
```

What determines your Logger Name is how you create it.

```cs
LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger() // The name will be "namespace.name" of the current class.
LogManager.GetLogger<T>() // The name will be "namespace.name" of the Type T.
LogManager.GetLogger(Type type)  // The name will be "namespace.name" of the type.
LogManager.GetLogger(string name)  // The name will be name.
```

So if you have a particular process that you want to log in multiple classes / files, define the name of the process and use the `string` overload.

If you want to be able to turn on logging for a single class, use one of the other overloads.

Comment: Your answer is correct here, but I think could be more clear.  It took me two read throughs to figure out that the first block and the second block were connected via name.